# volvo s40 2005 model, remote unresponsive

Tags: volvo, keyless-entry, fob, s40

I have a volvo s40 2005 model. I tryed locking it with the remote and it would not respond. Initially i thought it is because the battery for the remote is finished. I bought a new one and changed it. However, the car stil does not respond. What could be the problem? Currently i am locking manually, which means the alarm will not be set.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I can think of.

First, the car might have *lost* the remote. Meaning that it no longer recognizes that the remote and must relearn it (through programming or whatever).

Second, it could just be that the remote is broken and no longer works. Do you have other remotes which work? Is there an indicator light on the remote showing it is transmitting *something* or is at least attempting to?